# My foreach query is not working and i am getting an error

Tags: php, foreach

I am getting a Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() message with the code below.

The idea is that I have 2 tables, one is a stock table which has a large amount of data imported to it daily, and is linked.  The other table (although not a parent table) is a list of sites, they have a common field called StockName.

The idea of this code, is that, when run, it is supposed to loop through all of the sites in the site table, get the StockName field, then use that to lookup the latest value in the stockdetails table, and then update the Site table with up to date info.  Thats the theory, here is the code:

```
$rstmp = CustomQuery("SELECT * FROM Sites");
$datatmp = db_fetch_array($rstmp);
$SitePk = $datatmp['SitePk'];

foreach ($SitePk as $item)
{
echo $item."<BR>";
$rstmp2 = CustomQuery("SELECT * FROM ImportStockDetails where StockName='".$datatmp['StockName']."' ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT 1");
$datatmp2 = db_fetch_array($rstmp2);

$latestdate = $rstmp2["LastStockDate"];
$latestcylpropane = $rstmp2["PropaneCylinders"];
$latestcylbutane = $rstmp2["ButaneCylinders"];
$latestbulkpropane = $rstmp2["BulkPropane"];
$latestbulkbutane = $rstmp2["BulkButane"];
$latesttotal = $latestcylpropane+$latestcylbutane+$latestbulkpropane+$latestbulkbutane;
$latestratio = $latesttotal/$datatmp['SiteMaxCapacity'];

global $dal;
$dal_table = $dal->Table("Sites"); 
$dal_table->Param["SitePk"] = $item; 
$dal_table->Value["LatestPropaneCylinderStock"] = $latestcylpropane;
$dal_table->Value["LatestButaneCylinderStock"] = $latestcylbutane;
$dal_table->Value["LatestBulkPropaneStock"] = $latestbulkpropane;
$dal_table->Value["LatestBulkButaneStock"] = $latestbulkbutane;
$dal_table->Value["LatestTotalStock"] = $latesttotal;
$dal_table->Value["`Stock/LimitRatio`"] = $latestratio;
$dal_table->Value["LastStockDate"] = $latestdate;

$dal_table->Update();
}
```

Comment: Print out the contents of `$SitePk` and make sure it's what you expect it to be. We don't know what `CustomQuery` nor `db_fetch_array` do, but I'd bet your query is failing or returning something that isn't an array.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the warning because `$SitePk` is not an array, it is just a value. You should try with `$datatmp` as `db_fetch_array($rstmp);` return array which is stored in $datatmp.

Comment: like this...foreach ($datatmp as db_fetch_array($rstmp))?

Comment: actually on second thoughts, i think i want to use the query to get the latest value.  Can someone point me to an article that tells me how to have a MySQL query where the field value is a "subquery", eg linking tables by StockName and returning latest date for that value?

Comment: Use it like this ```$datatmp = db_fetch_array($rstmp); foreach ($datatmp as $item){}```.

Comment: You can you SQL JOIN for your purpose.

Comment: ok i am trying this, and its not working, its nested within an existing SELECT FROM query and is a sub line...ie a query within a query.  (SELECT BulkPropane as test1 FROM ImportStockDetails ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT 1 WHERE Sites.StockName = ImportStockDetails.StockName) subquery1